# How to install i915_bo driver in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics, i915, skylake

The chosen answer [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/715006/40540) mentions the installation of the i915_bo driver.

I have the same OS (Linux Mint 17.3), but I'm running the i915 driver.

Can someone please tell me where do I find it and how to install the i915_bo?

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer there that might have solved your problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/700601/494287

Install the intel graphics installer, and try installing the drivers.

You seem to be able to run Ubuntu programs in Linux Mint just fine...